# Calling a method in a class, in an if/elif statement

Tags: class, python-2.7, if-statement, methods

i'm creating trying to create a project, but i'm running into an error.

This is my code (not all of it, it's pretty lengthy, but the problem i'm running into):

```
class Rest(object):
    def __init__(self, name, order=[], total=0):
        self.name = name
        self.order = []
        self.total = 0
    def end_order(self):
        print("Here is your complete order: {0}".format(self.order))
        print("Here is your total: {0}".format(self.total))
    def order_menu(self):
        loop = 1
        while (loop == 1):
            question_1 = raw_input("What would you like? Push S to Submit, Push C to Cancel")
            if (question_1 == "1"):
                self.total += 4.99
                print("You added a cheeseburger, $4.99)
            elif (question_1 == "S"):
                end_order()
```

Okay, so under order_menu(self), under the elif statement, it gives me an error:
"Global name 'end_order()' is not defined".

There's a probably something silly i'm not doing, but I can't figure out what..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `self` keyword is required in Python when calling a class method. Try:

```
self.end_order()
```

Comment: I'm guessing 'accept it' means like flag or vote up? I can't vote up, sorry i'm not too sure what you mean, i'm new to stackoverflow..

Comment: @GregH Click the outlined checkmark to turn it green. This will make it the official "answer" for your question. This will also mark the question as answered and stop it from showing up in the "unanswered" filter.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks, I know how this for future questions!